# check if string contains specific integer

Tags: vb.net

I have a grid view that has a column containing strings (Middle column).

[image: Gridview]

On the `rowDataBound` event I want to loop through the column looking for the integer it contains and then display a value in the first column.

I know that the integer range will be 1 to 63 so I can use a `FOR loop` to loop through the numbers.  Here is what I have so far.

```
For x As Integer = 1 To 63

If CType(e.Row.Cells(2).FindControl("lblTagName"), Label).Text Then

End If

Next
```

The problem I am having is using `contains`.  I cant use the following as it would also be true for the number 1, 10, 11 etc when `x = 1`.

```
For x As Integer = 1 To 63

If CType(e.Row.Cells(2).FindControl("lblTagName"), Label).Text.Contains(x) Then

End If

Next
```

How do I make sure it only gets one result per number?  i.e `x = 6` would return UMIS.75OPTR6GROSSMARGIN.F_CV and not all the other strings that contain the number 6.

UPDATE - based on some answers I may not of explained this very well.  I want to loop through the gridview and if the number 1 is found and only the number 1 in the second column, not 10 etc then I want to display "Run 1" in the first column.  So when x = 10 it will show "Run 10" and so on.

UPDATE 2 - its definatley my explanation, apologies.

The resultant grid view would look like this.

[image: Resultant gridview]

The order of the second column is not set and is not in order.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to check the *entire* text of the label to determine whether it is only `1`, and not `10, 11, 12, 13, ...` as well.

Also, in this case you should use [**`DirectCast`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) rather than [**`CType`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx). `CType` is only used when converting to ***different*** types that include conversion operators, here you are always dealing with a label.

```
For x As Integer = 1 To 63

    If String.Equals(DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(2).FindControl("lblTagName"), Label).Text, "UMIS.75OPTR" & x & "GROSSMARGIN.F_CV", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        'Do your stuff.
    End If

Next
```

Comment: @Silentbob : No problem, sometimes it's hard to explain to others what you want to do with your code :). Glad I could help! -- Also, note that because I am using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` the match is case-insensitive. Thus, it won't matter if the label's text is for example `umis.75opTr6grOSsmargIN.F_Cv`, as long as it's the same characters.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think if doing it the other way around. Get the list of numbers in your string with a regular expression match.

```
    Dim s As String = "asd12asdasd.sdf3sdf"

    For Each m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(s, "[\d]*")
        If m.Success AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value) Then
            ' m.Value
        End If
    Next
```

With that list of number, you can check if it's between 1 and 63.

If your string have the same suffix/prefix, just remove them to show you what the number is.

```
    Dim s As String = "UMIS.75OPTR12GROSSMARGIN.F_CV"
    Dim number As String = s.Replace("UMIS.75OPTR", "").Replace("GROSSMARGIN.F_CV", "")
```

Comment: For the Regex example, keep in mind that his string starts with "UMIS. **75** ".

Answer (score 0):

Go backwards in a Do Until Loop:

```
Dim bolFoundMatch As Boolean = False
Dim intCursor As Integer = 63

Do Until (bolFoundMatch OrElse intCursor = 0)

     If CType(e.Row.Cells(2).FindControl("lblTagName"), Label).Text.Contains(intCursor) Then

          'Anything you want to do when you find your match.

          'This will ensure your loop exits.
          bolFoundMatch = True

     End If 

     intCursor -= 1

Loop
```

Comment: surely if intcursor = 1 then it will stop at 61 whereas i want to go to 1

Comment: That's why I have it going backwards.  61 will stop the loop before it gets to 1.

Comment: But he wants it to go _**from 1 and up**_, not the other way around.

Comment: Oh, totally missed that.

Comment: and it needs to go through the entire grid.  See my update

Comment: @Silentbob : I don't get it... You want it to stop once it has found a match, but you also want it to go through the entire grid??

Comment: No I dont want it to stop

Comment: If you go backwards then you know it's the one and only match.  No point in looping through the others.  You still want to loop through all of the grid results, but not the processing of determining the integer for that particular row.

Comment: @Silentbob : But if all labels are located in the order `1-63`, then you will only get one match per number every time you iterate. -- I think you have to give us an example of what you're doing when you get a match, what is wrong with that, and how it should turn out.

Comment: it has to go through the entire grid, the issue is that when it finds 1 put something specific in column1  (same row as where it is found) and when it finds 2 then put something in column 1 (same row as where it is found).  The issue is that 10 has the integer 1 in it and so does 11, 12, 13 I want the integer to be specific i.e just 1 not 11.